# Why are we getting multiple parts?

Tags: solr

I am trying to achieve something similar to [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-CombiningStatsComponentWithPivots).

I don't understand why are there two inStock[count=8 and count=4]. Why can't they combine and return as single json object?

1. What is the reason?
2. Is there any way to combine it?

Ans Suggestions?

```
{
 "field": "cat",
  "value": "electronics",
  "count": 12,
  "pivot": [
    {
      "field": "inStock",
      "value": true,
      "count": 8,
      "stats": {
        "stats_fields": {
          "price": {
            "min": 74.98999786376953,
            "max": 399.0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "field": "inStock",
      "value": false,
      "count": 4,
      "stats": {
        "stats_fields": {
          "price": {
            "min": 11.5,
            "max": 649.989990234375
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "stats": {
    "stats_fields": {
      "price": {
        "min": 11.5,
        "max": 649.989990234375
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you given cat,inStock fields to facet.pivot

Ex: cat=[electronics, currency] inStock=True or False

As per your example consider you have say 16 products, 12 being electronics and 4 related to currency

for every category it check how many are inStock=true and inStock=False

```
"field": "cat",
  "value": "electronics",
  "count": 12,
    pivot": [
        {
          "field": "inStock",
          "value": true,
          "count": 8,
          "stats": {
            "stats_fields": {
              "price": {
                "min": 74.98999786376953,
                "max": 399.0
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "field": "inStock",
          "value": false,
          "count": 4,
          "stats": {
            "stats_fields": {
              "price": {
                "min": 11.5,
                "max": 649.989990234375
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
```

out of 12 electronics products 8 are inStock=True and 4 are inStock=False.

you might have given price for stats field. so it gives maximum and minimum price values in all cat[electronics, currency] and inStock[True or False] groups.

in your case electronics products which are inStock=True(8 products).
out of 8 price values its showing max and min value i.e

```
"min": 74.98999786376953,
 "max": 399.0
```

also it gives maximum and minimum values in all electronics products which are inStock=False (4 products) i.e

```
"min": 11.5,
  "max": 649.989990234375
```

it gives same statistics for remaining category also.

Comment: just give cat field for facet.pivot `facet.pivot=cat` then you get stats on only cat field, it wont show 8 and 4 stats of inStock field.

Comment: Got the same. Thanks. Figured it out with my samples. And your answer made me to change my assumption to answer.